# Swift/Xcode - Create UI Notification alert like Instagram using Firebase?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I was wondering how could I achieve a notification alert similar to instagram. I do not mean push-notifications, rather when using the app the pop-up with an icon. I have attached an image to help clarify what I mean:

[This type of notification](https://www.flickr.com/photos/dannyloes/7978267175)

I am using firebase and do have methods that detect if a users had liked/commented or even followed you. However, the only way to see these notifications is by actually tapping on the notification button which loads the `Notification ViewController`. I wish to display the notification when any of the aforementioned events occur regardless of where the user is with regards to using my app whether it's the home view or search view etc.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the [AMPopTip](https://github.com/andreamazz/AMPopTip#showing-a-custom-view) library on GitHub and set up a custom view that shows the information you want, as described in their Readme:

> You can provide a custom view that will be wrapped in the PopTip and
>   presented.
>
> ```
> let customView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
> // Configure your view 
> popTip.show(customView: customView, direction: .down, in: view, from: someView.frame)
> ```